# NameError: name 'bmi_calculator' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to make a bmi calculator but I am getting a NameError issue even though I have defined the bmi calculator. My code is like this:-

```
name1 = 'Person1'
height1_m = 1.7
weight1_kg = 54

name2 = 'Person2'
height2_m = 2
weight2_kg = 70

name3 = 'Person3'
height3_m = 1
weight3_kg = 1000

def bmi_calculator(name, height_m, weight_kg):
    bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    print(name + "'s bmi is: " + bmi)
    if bmi > 25
        print(name + 'is overweight')
    else
        print(name + 'is not overweight')

result1 = bmi_calculator(name1, height1_m, weight1_kg)
result2 = bmi_calculator(name2, height2_m, weight2_kg)
result3 = bmi_calculator(name3, height3_m, weight3_kg)

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-31aab3e09e71> in <module>
----> 1 result1 = bmi_calculator(name1, height1_m, weight1_kg)
      2 result2 = bmi_calculator(name2, height2_m, weight2_kg)
      3 result3 = bmi_calculator(name3, height3_m, weight3_kg)

NameError: name 'bmi_calculator' is not defined
```

Comment: did you run the cell which define your function?

Comment: I don't think that error can come from that code. How are you entering/running it? If it were a single script it would work. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Problem was, colon (**:**) at the end of **if** and **else** is required.

2nd problem was, you were trying to convert **float** to **str** implicitly.

This would work:

```
name1 = 'Person1'
height1_m = 1.7
weight1_kg = 54

name2 = 'Person2'
height2_m = 2
weight2_kg = 70

name3 = 'Person3'
height3_m = 1
weight3_kg = 1000

def bmi_calculator(name, height_m, weight_kg):
    bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    print(str(name) + "'s bmi is: " + str(bmi))
    if bmi > 25:
        print(name + 'is overweight')
    else:
        print(name + 'is not overweight')

result1 = bmi_calculator(name1, height1_m, weight1_kg)
result2 = bmi_calculator(name2, height2_m, weight2_kg)
result3 = bmi_calculator(name3, height3_m, weight3_kg)
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @PeterWood I have edited my answer please check.